# Fitting data with a Voigt function

Tags: nonlinear-equations, nonlinear-programming, least-squares, curve-fitting

I have some data, (xrd data), that I would like peak fit with a pseudo-Voigt function, a combination of a Gaussian and a Lorentzian function. These are the functions

$G(x) = I \exp\left( -\frac{4\ln(2)(x-\Theta)^2}{w_G}\right)$

$L(x) = I \frac{w_{L}^2}{w_{L}^2+\left(x-\Theta\right)^2}$

Where $I$ is the intensity, $\Theta$ is the peak position, $w_G$ and $w_L$ are the full width at half maximum for the Gaussian and the Lorentzian respectively, together they form the Voigt function

$V(x) = \eta L(x) + (1-\eta)G(x)$

where $\eta$ is a mixing parameter

The unknowns are $I$, $\Theta$, $w_G$, $w_L$, and $\eta$. The data is given by $x$.

I want to fit the data with the method of least squares, MSE, but since the problem is nonlinear, I find it to be quite a pain.
for would i have read I need to solve the Hessian for only the five unknown parameters, but I don't quite understand the math of what this solves.

So the question is, what is the math to solve this problem and if able to, some pseudo-code?

Comment: Do your data consist of x,V pairs and do you have some data you can make available?

Comment: the data is intensity as function of x, the Voigt(x) function is just the fitting function, therefore the five unknown parameters is found trough the method of least squares

Comment: And do you have sample data available?

Comment: It might be published so I cant upload the data, tho the data is from a XRD measurement over a single peak

Comment: If you cannot share a data sample, then you should generate a synthetic one.

Comment: There are many suitable "canned" routines for nonlinear least-squares fitting. What is your preferred programming language?

Comment: @endulum I have a program that fits the curve, I just try to understand the math of it and what numerically the program is doing